# Updating TextField from different class than GUI

Tags: java, swing, class, user-interface

I'm trying to update the GUI from a different Class. Every time I have tried calling the method on a different class it doesn't work but If I do it in the GUI Class it works just fine.

GUI Class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test7 extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
 private JButton jcomp1;
 private JButton jcomp2;
 private JButton jcomp3;
 private JTextField jcomp4;

 public Test7() {
  //construct components
  jcomp1 = new JButton("Button 1");
  jcomp2 = new JButton("Button 2");
  jcomp3 = new JButton("Button 3");
  jcomp4 = new JTextField(5);
  jcomp1.addActionListener(this);


  //adjust size and set layout
  setPreferredSize(new Dimension(723, 455));
  setLayout(null);

  //add components
  add(jcomp1);
  add(jcomp2);
  add(jcomp3);
  add(jcomp4);

  //set component bounds (only needed by Absolute Positioning)
  jcomp1.setBounds(160, 320, 100, 20);
  jcomp2.setBounds(340, 320, 100, 20);
  jcomp3.setBounds(490, 315, 140, 20);
  jcomp4.setBounds(180, 125, 365, 110);
 }


 public static void main(String[] args) {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyPanel");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.getContentPane().add(new Test7());
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
 }

 public void setTextArea(JTextField jcomp4) {

  this.jcomp4 = jcomp4;

 }


 public JTextField getTextArea() {
  return this.jcomp4;
 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
  if (e.getSource() == jcomp1) {    
   Class class1 = new Class();
   class1.start();    
  }
 }
}
```

Second Class:

```
public class Class extends Test7{

        public void start(){
            Test7 form = new Test7();
            form.getTextArea().setText("nesto");
        }
}
```

I have also tried putting the code on a same Thread but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Test7` is JPanel. It is added to JFrame in your main method. When you call `Class.start()` you create new `Test7`. This new JPanel is not related to JPanel previously added to JFrame, so it is not even visible.

Your `Class` class should neither extend nor create new `Test7` instance. Instead `Test7` instance could be passed in constructor to `Class`:

```
Class class1 = new Class(this);
class1.start();
```

Your `Class` class:

```
public class Class {

    private final Test7 test;

    public Class(Test7 test) {
        super();
        this.test = test;
    }

    public void start() {
        test.getTextArea().setText("nesto");

    }
}
```

Andrew`s comments are also worthwile to think about.